# Trash folder not a directory, files only delete immediately

Tags: macos, terminal, mac, finder, trash

Trash is not storing files any more. When I drag something to the trash it only presents the option to delete the item immediately and that I can't undo the change. I had a look at the folder in terminal:

```
$ ls -ld ~/.Trash
----------  1 Nic  staff  0 13 Aug 08:35 /User/Nic/.Trash
```

When I remove the Trash with:

```
$ rm -rf ~/.Trash
```

and restart the computer, it works for a few days, then it stops working again.

Comment: You have a program that gets things wrong - so you have to look at each one. Start by looking at console.app for entries about the time of the bad file

Answer (score 3):

Your trash has been turned into a plain file with no permissions.

```
rm ~/.Trash
mkdir -m 700 ~/.Trash
```

and normality should be restored.